# Deployment issue in viewing PDF using react-pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, react-pdf

I used react-pdf to display a single-page PDF in a ReactJS application. It worked well during the development stage, but after deployment, it stopped working. It says, "Failed to load the pdf". What happened there, and how can I solve it? It would be a great help if you could assist me.

Comment: Without the code I don't think I can provide more in-sign. But the first thing that comes into mind is that probably the file gets blocked because of CORS or something around that, since as you mentioned it works in your dev build.

Answer (score 0):

```js
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;

//Make sure you use this in the deployment stage instead of 

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL("pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js", import.meta.url).toString();
```